# Intellij IDEA problems with connections to DB

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I've imported spring-boot maven project from git. This project uses Mysql. 
I've created database with customized name in workbench.

application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password= root
```

the same credentials i put into intellij's db-connection window.
When i click on "Test connection" i've got:

```
Connection to myDb@localhost failed.
[42000][1049] Unknown database 'myDb'
```

Pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
.....
```

============Updated==============

Apllication can't start with an error:

```
    2018-04-26 13:12:22.404 ERROR 3988 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter    : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'jwtFilterRegistration' defined in com.edsson.expopromoter.api.Application: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jwtFilterRegistration' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [C:\Users\koliada\Desktop\IdeaProjects\ExpoPromoter\expopromoter-api\target\classes\com\edsson\expopromoter\api\user\service\UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#64607e71' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#64607e71': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
2018-04-26 13:12:22.428  WARN 3988 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2018-04-26 13:12:22.478 ERROR 3988 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.edsson.expopromoter.api.user.service.UserService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
```

Comment: Does your application start up and is able to find the DB?

Comment: I've updated. check please

Comment: The error you are encountering has nothing to do with IntelliJ. Your database is not reachable on your local machine.

Comment: Seems like you are right. Anyway can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it says

> Unknown database 'myDb'

so have you checked if this database already exist?

As intellij's db-connection can not reach that database, so the problem could exist in your connect param(URL,username,password) or mysql, not the code.

Comment: Problem was that i didn't create schema in DB